# Hyperjaxb: Override cascade for an element in a complexType

Tags: java, hyperjaxb

I'm using the default cascade options Hyperjaxb assigns. However, there is an exceptional case where I need to override. Suppose I have a type defined as follows:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DogType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="cac:DogOwner" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element ref="cac:FavoriteFood" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now, obviously when I remove a Dog, its owner should not be deleted. However, the default cascade option for DogOwner is `ALL`. How can I override the CascadeType for DogOwner so it cascades in all cases except `REMOVE`?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't give the full answer at the moment, but check [this example project](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources/schema.xsd), it gives a pretty good idea of how you can customize generated mappings.